# Linearlayout for different screen sizes

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, screen-size

I have a linearLayout which is surrounded by a scrollView in order to make it for smaller screens scrollable. In the linear layout I have 3 childs which are also linearlayout.

This is working fine. But I also want to support larger screens. At the moment I get with a larger screen space left on the bottom of the screen. I want to have the buttons (navigation bar) be always at the bottom. for larger screens (height) I would like to add at the top of the screen an empty view which fills out the space that is more provided by the larger screen.

How can I achieve that? i tried a lot with weight attribute but didnt get it working.

Here the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="#8db9f6"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#8db9f6">
        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:text="test"
                android:id="@+id/test"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>
            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnName"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit">
            </ImageButton>
        </LinearLayout>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittest"
            android:editable="false"
            android:hint="@string/test"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </EditText>
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/optionalText"
            android:id="@+id/test1"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="12dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </TextView>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/space"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_height="3sp"
            android:background="#333142">
        </TextView>
        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:text="TEST TESt"
                android:id="@+id/test2"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>
            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:id="@+id/progressbar"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/btnPicture"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit">
            </ImageButton>
        </LinearLayout>
        <FrameLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dip">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/test3"
                android:layout_width="400dip"
                android:layout_height="150dip"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/test1"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="8dp"
                android:text="test test"/>
        </FrameLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/scaleMinus"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="@string/zoomOut"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/scalePlus"
                android:textSize="14dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:text="@string/zoomIn"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/balken"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_height="3sp"
            android:background="#333142">
        </TextView>
        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:text="test test"
                android:id="@+id/test3"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>
            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/test4"
                android:editable="false"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </EditText>
            <TextView
                android:text="test"
                android:id="@+id/mtest4"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            </TextView>
            <View
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/test5"
                android:scaleType="center"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit">
            </ImageButton>
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/balken"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
            android:layout_height="3sp"
            android:background="#333142">
        </TextView>
        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="#000000"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/save"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="@string/save"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/cancel"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="@string/abort"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Have you tried using fill_parent in the layouts?. Can you post the layout.xml to see what it looks like so we can help you better?

Comment: yes I have set fill_parent. I will post the layout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the entire layout in a Relative Layout.  Use a relative layout as your root element and set the Linear Layout containing your buttons to layout_alignParentBottom="true" and the ScrollView set to layout_alignParentTop="true".

The LinearLayout containing the buttons and the ScrollView should be direct children of the RelativeLayout.

```
<RelativeLayout
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
         <LinearLayout <-- containing the layout minus the buttons
               android:id="@+id/SV"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
            <The Rest Of The Layout>
         </LinearLayout>
         <LinearLayout
               android:id="@+id/LLButtons"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
          <Buttons>
          </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

If you want the buttons to be always at the bottom of the screen alignParentBottom.  If you want the buttons to always be at the bottom of the scrollview alignBelow="@id/SV"

Comment: Thx. But there does the ScrollView start?

Comment: ok thx, this is nice. But now the space is above the buttons. I want it on the top of the screen.

Comment: You want the layout anchored to the bottom of the screen and any empty space at the top?  No problem.  Buttons = alignParentBottom=true & the LL with the rest of the layout will be alignAbove="@id/LLButtons"

Comment: thx. I have a further question. Is it possible to increase the linearLayout which contains the navigation buttons if I have a larger screen which gives me some space left (which I now have at top of the screen)?

Comment: You will asign a layout_weight parameter to the top level Linear Layouts.  This will have them expand, shrink depending on the weight set to each.

Comment: What weight value do I have to use?

Comment: check out this answer.  Explains it a lot better than I can. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-is-androidlayout-weight-meaning

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_height="wrap_content"` in your inner LinearLayout is your trouble here, changing it to 'fill_parent' should help.  In general, you may want to use hierarchyviewer to help troubleshoot layout issues like this.

Comment: I have 3 inner linearlayouts. should I use for all of them fill_parent for height?